# Constraint a password to have at least x special characters?

Tags: string, validation, .net-4.0, char, special-characters

I need a function that returns whether the given string contains at least x special characters.

I prefer it shouldn't be hardcoded.

Pseudo code:

```
public bool IsValid(string password, int minSpecialCharacters)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
    return
      password.Count(c => char.IsSpecialCharacter(c)) < minSpecialCharacters;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: And what language would you like this in?

Comment: There's an easy solution : count everything non-alphanumeric (ie `[^A-Za-z0-9]`) as a special character. Counting them in a string is simple too.

Comment: @Arefact2 I can't understand why u dont post this as answer do you want other to do it and gain your reputation!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `char.IsLetterOrDigit`, negated:

```
public bool IsValid(string password, int minSpecialCharacters)
{
    return password.Count(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)) >= minSpecialCharacters;
}
```